# On OS X 10.10.1 how to re-install Java 6 over Java 8

Tags: java

I have read everything (I am not expert).

I followed the instructions under Java for OS X 2014-001 how to re-enable the Apple provided Java 6.
I did everything but it did not work.
After that, `java -version` keeps telling me I have Java 1.8
If I type `/usr/libexec/java_home -verbose` I get the following:

```
1.8.0_25, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I need to go back to java 1.6 to run a molecular graphics pymol program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variable JAVA_HOME.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

If you want to make the change permantent you can add this line to `~/.profile`.